# Update ViewModel with async value, after/during call to ShowDialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

I'm creating a modal window, assigning it's `DataContext` to my view model, then calling `ShowDialog`.

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();  // implements INotifyPropertyChanged

// populate vm properties here

var window = new MyWindow(); // inherits from System.Windows.Window
window.DataContext = vm;
window.ShowDialog();
```

However, I want to populate properties of the viewmodel from the results of an `async` method.

```
vm.Result = await provider.GetResultAsync();
```

and I want those changes to be visible to data-bound properties in the window.

I can't do this before the call to `ShowDialog`, because then `ShowDialog` will only be called after the result is available.

I can't do this after the call to `ShowDialog`, because `ShowDialog` blocks until the window is closed.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Wowo Ot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897555/111794) and [@Marlonchonsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61898019/111794), I am doing the following:

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();
var window = new MyWindow();
window.DataContext = vm;
window.Loaded += async (s, e) => vm.Result = await provider.GetResultAsync();
window.ShowDialog();
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

move this code inside MyWindow Class

then in window_loaded()

```
var vm = new MyViewModel();  // implements INotifyPropertyChanged

// populate vm properties here

this.DataContext = vm;
```

Comment: 1) Can  this be done using `await`-ed results? 2) I can attach to the `Loaded` event outside of `MyWindow`. This is important, because in my case `MyWindow` is defined in a different DLL, and I can't really change it.

Comment: I think await / async depend on the provider .

Comment: For the purpose of the question, you can safely assume `provider` has an `async` method called `GetResultAsync` which returns a `Task`-ed value.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: sorry I couldn't help !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways. I recommend the @WowoOt's answer since the view model must be part of your window in which you are trying to be using.

Another way of accomplishing it, is to use the [Task.ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1) method in the call of `provider.GetResultAsync()`, and then write the assigment `vm.Result = task.Response` in the callback. However, this only works if your view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here is the code for this:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // Supposed to open the window after clicking a button.
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    var window = new MyWindow {
        DataContext = vm
    };
    //vm.Result = await GetResultAsync();
    _ = GetResultAsync().ContinueWith(x => vm.Result = x.Result);

    window.ShowDialog();

    static async Task<string> GetResultAsync() {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // just to simulate a long process to recover the data.
        return $"generated string: {new Random().Next(10)}";
    }
}
```

My sample view model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`  interface, to notify the XAML framework about any changes in its properties.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string result;
    public string Result {
        get => this.result;
        set {
            this.result = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: 1) The viewmodel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, as noted in the question. 2) Why do I need to introduce a new local function? `_ = provider.GetResultAsync().ContinueWith(x => vm.Result = x.Result);` should work just as well. 3) _the view model must be part of the window in which you are trying to use it_ Not really. The same window could use different view model types, and the same viewmodel type could be applied to multiple views. 4) Why do I need to assign to a discard (`_`)?

Comment: @ZevSpitz in the code, the local function is to give a complete solution, you need to replace it with your provider's method. The intend to use a view model is to shape the elements in your UIElement (Window, UserControl, etc.), so you don't need to write multiples view models for a view.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
vm.GetResultsTask = provider.GetResultsAsync();
```

Then when you need the results in the MyWindow you will do 
`await DataContext.GetResultsTask` to get them.

Comment: I don't have code that explicitly gets the results; I am relying on databinding. When should I write `await DataContext.GetResultsTask;`?

Comment: I would suggest incorporating this information in your answer. Assuming this works, I prefer it, because it could encapsulate the result retrieval in the view model.